# removing a placed jquery click event listener after initial click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Got some simple functionality set up on a page. Initially I want to replace default action of a hyperlink click with some functionality which will display an overlay.

After the overlay is displayed I want to remove the event listener I have placed on the hyperlink so it reverts to what it was previously (i believe there is another event listener on here, I dont want to remove this one while removing mine). Within the overlay is another button which when clicked, should trigger the initial functionality of the button.

Ive tried the .off() jquery method, however this seems to prevent the ".mmclose" button from working.

Not quite sure where i am going wrong with this..

```
// placing event listener on initial link
$("#utility_0_HyperLinkLogout").click(function() {
  // removing event listener(?)
  $("#utility_0_HyperLinkLogout").off("click");
  // preventing default button behavior
  event.preventDefault();
  //overlay replacing original content
  I62originalContent.hide();
  $("#mmi62wrapper").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // new event listener placed on button within overlay (as callback)        
    $(".mmclose").click(function() {
      //new button should now trigger original buttons original functionality?
      $("#utility_0_HyperLinkLogout").trigger("click");
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding a copy of it? The new copy would not have the previous one's event listeners.

Comment: Yeah i thought of that, it was sort of my last resort though, seemed a bit inelegant

Comment: You could also go for a global boolean variable that is used like a latch. Initially false but first click could make it true and alter the functionality within the click event handler.

Comment: Try hit the DOM click handler direct: `$("#utility_0_HyperLinkLogout")[0].click()`. Also just use `one()` and not `click()` to handler a one-off click situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.one` method to attach a handler which will be executed only once. You don't need to worry about removing this handler anymore.

Check this example:

```js
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  this.innerText += "!";
});

$("#myId").one('click', function() {
  this.innerText += "?";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myClass" id="myId">Click me twice</button>
```

In this example, clicking the button keeps adding "!", while "?" is only added once. Other handlers are not affected.